# how to add window to usercontrol in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to add Window border to usercontrol in WPF?

Comment: Do you mean something like adding a TitleBar and Min/Max/Close buttons to a dialog control?

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative source binding:

```
BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=BorderBrush}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Border` tag to get window border to your usercontrol, like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1" ------->        
<Border Width="310" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="LightBlue"  BorderThickness="1">
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="File" Grid.Column="0" Height="22" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
    <Button Content="Browse..." Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Height="25" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1,1,5,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"></Button>
</Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use user control as content of a window .

you can set more property of window if you like

```
 Window w = new Window() {Content=new **YourUserControlHere**,Width=400,Height =400,...  };
w.ShowDialog();
```

[CheckHere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208497/wpf-window-hosting-usercontrol)